# Python tkinter: changing color for a recently clicked button

Tags: python, button, callback, tkinter, parameter-passing

I'm trying to have a program which would have a grid of 8x8 buttons which would on-click change their color
My code looks like this:

```
def Function(self):
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            a=Button(self,width=2,height=1,command=lambda widget="button"+str(i)+str(j):Click1(self,widget))
            a.grid(row=i,column=j)

def Click1(self):
    a["bg"]="blue"
```

The problem I have with this is that I keep getting an error saying:

```
NameError: name 'Click1' is not defined
```

any solutions for this?

Comment: Without running this to verify it, I bet you need to write `self.Click1(widget)` in your command, rather than `Click1(self, widget)`. But if this fixes the error, I bet you'll get a new error `Click1 takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` because you're passing `self` and `widget` to a function that is only expecting `self`. And if you fix that by adding `widget` to the `def`, I bet you'll get `NameError: a is not defined`. And if you change `a` to `widget`, I bet you'll get `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`... Boy, this is tricky!

Comment: You guessed everything except the last one:
    TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not saving references to the Buttons, so you can't change them later on. What you should do is save references to the Buttons, for example in a list of lists (like a grid), so you can access them with the row and column number.

Here's a working example:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def Function(self):
        self.grid = []
        for i in range(8):
            row = []
            for j in range(8):
                row.append(Button(self.root,width=2,height=1,command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.Click1(i, j)))
                row[-1].grid(row=i,column=j)
            self.grid.append(row)

    def Click1(self, i, j):
        self.grid[i][j]["bg"]="blue"

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.Function()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered all my questions!